# Oracle performance with respect to index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I am executing below query on table `col_log_actionrequest`. It has index on column `szorgcode`, `cstatus`, `szpartitionfield` and `szactioncode`. Column `szpartitionfield` is partitioned column. Suppose this table has two partition `'MH'` and `'BIH'`. `'BIH'` has only 10% data of `'MH'`.

When I execute this query:

```
select *
  from prodcoll.col_log_actionrequest ab
 where  szorgcode = '001'
   and cstatus ='D'
-- and szactioncode = 'UBAR'
   and szpartitionfield = 'BIH';
```

it gives full table scan. But, when I use `szpartitionfield='MH'`, it gives index range scan on index of `cstatus` column. May I know why?

Also if I execute below query irrespective of partitionfield,

```
select *
  from prodcoll.col_log_actionrequest ab
 where szorgcode = '001'
   and cstatus = 'D'
   and szactioncode = 'UBAR'
   and szpartitionfield = 'BIH';
```

It gives index range scan on index on `szactioncode`. Why is it so?

Why optimizer doesn't use other index?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have single index for each field, just create a composite index.

```
CREATE INDEX comp_ind 
ON prodcoll.col_log_actionrequest(szorgcode, cstatus, szactioncode, szpartitionfield);
```

And maybe another for the 3 fields.

The reason for when the optimizer choose use the index or not depend on the size of the table and number of elements of each type, sometime using the index cost more than just do the full scan.

In this case use 4 separated index is too expensive. Because optimizer can use all together and need look up the table after each search.

Comment: these all are different different composite indexes. I can not create any more index. I just want to know when I change szpartitionfield='MH' then it shows index range scan on index of cstatus column. But same for szpartitionfield='BIH', it won't allow. May I know why?